# How to break line in language generation file in botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

I have long text line in the language generation file of my bot. How to break line of code to improve visibility?

```
# PromptForDestinationCity
- Where would you like to travel to? There are plenty of options. Just choose one. Or do whatever else you would like to. Enjoy!
- What is your destination city?
```

into this (but it will result with error)

```
# PromptForDestinationCity
- Where would you like to travel to? There are plenty of options. Just choose one. Or
do whatever else you would like to. Enjoy!
- What is your destination city?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-language-generation#simple-response-template) on multiline text.

Basically:

````
# PromptForDestinationCity
- ``` Where would you like to travel to? 
      There are plenty of options. 
      Just choose one. Or do whatever else you would like to. Enjoy!
  ```
- What is your destination city?
````